# How can I add tags to favourites in the iOS app?

Tags: support, ios-app, tag-watching

I am pretty sure it was possible to add tags to your favourite tags list in the app, but now I can't find this function any more. Similarly, I can't find a way to delete existing tags from my favourites in the app.

Comment: My question got marked as duplicate, but it's not possible to edit tags in the way described in the linked answer (at least for me) anymore. Was this funtion intentionally removed or will it be reinstated with an update?